# Compatibility between VBA and MySQL on Excel for Windows and Mac

Tags: mysql, vba, windows, macos

I'm coding an app in VBA which is linked to an Access Database. My app is already functional. I import the data from the Access DB in Excel sheets, and use it, classic isn't it.
As you may know, Access ins't available for MacOs, so I can't update or get any data from my Access DB when my VBA app runs on Mac.
I know that you I link MySQL with VBA using ADODB, replacing my Access DB by doing so.
My question is: if I have a MySQL DB on a Mac, and I want to pass it to a Windows computer, is it possible? Do I need to simply copy/past a database file?
Will there be any incompatibility in the files format between the 2 Os which could cause any problems?
My app will be used by several people who use both windows and Mac, and need to work on the latest updated database, so Access isn't a viable option.
Thanks!

Comment: If your application is hosted separate databases on each computer, then keeping those databases synced will be a nightmare. It is better to have a single shared database, or have a central shared database + local databases for disconnected operations, but then you need to put in syncing functionality and handling of conflicts between the disparate data sets. This is going to get ugly very soon.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is happy to run on both OS. So, as long as the end user is and has a running copy of MySQL, then I see little reason why the database file can't be transferred. You never opening or connecting to a file, but to that of MySQL server database. In fact, it don't matter if MySQL is running on a Linux server - windows or Mac clients can connect to such databases without issues.

So, the only real issue here is that you have to have MySQL database server up and running - and you have to have as such in all cases, since you not connecting to a file like MS-Access but are in fact making a socket tp/ip connection to a database server.

So you need more then just a transfer of the MySQL database file - you need MYSQL as as sytem/server running in all cases. But as far as I know, MySQL database files are compatible between different platforms running MySQL. The only common issue is that of having a running server instance of MySQL.

Comment: Ok I got your point. I don’t think I’ll be able to have such a server. Do you know any other solutions? 
Let’s be honest though, my DB contained 5 tables and the biggest one won’t contain more than 10k entries (I doubt it will be more than 2k entries but just seing large), so it could be an idea to use XML files to store and pass each table between the computers?

Comment: Well using MySQL was your suggestion - so I kind of assumed it was a possible. You could perhaps store the data in Excel sheets, or as you possible suggest csv files. Or you could adopt a light weight tiny database say like sqlite that runs on both platforms.  I don't know if a ADDOB provider exists for sqlIte, but a ODBC one certainly does on the windows side - check if sqlite has ODBC drivers for mac - it probably does.

Comment: Yes ODBC does, I’ll look at both CSV/XML files and SQLite. Thanks for your advice. I’ll close the question.

Comment: No, you cannot just simply copy over mysql data files from one server to another and expect it to work. It's not that simple.

Comment: Does not MySQL support moving db files between different servers? I would assume that some form of attach, and then detach option exists here? Or simply copying the db files from one server to another into the correct folder is not possible? If this is not possible like it is with most server databases, then you are suggesting this is one of the worlds worst database systems ever built and created? So, sure, their may well be more steps then a simple file copy - but this is certainly possible with most database systems. Do Linux/mac versions use different file formats then windows?

Comment: Does a copy / paste of a DB file work with SQLite? Access is easy, a shame it isn’t available on MacOS. MySql seems to split its tables into various files making it hard to copy paste it looks like.

Comment: yes, a simple copy file for the db + sqlite will work. It is a file based version (not sevice based) of sqlIte. There is also I suppose the embeeded version of MySQL. But yes - without question sqlite would give you a database system, one that does not need to be installed (xcopy install), and it would/should run + work on both platforms. The only trick part is ensuring that  a ODBC driver is installed on both systems - that's a bit of a hassle, but certainly far less then using MYSQL as a server system - a server based system is somewhat over-kill here anyway.